# Why the different NSFileHandle flavors and how are they implemented?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Relatively new to Cocoa here.
This question is about NSFileHandle, but I got a feeling the answer may be relevant in a broader Cocoa programming context.

I'm just wondering:

- why there are different NSFileHandle constructor flavors (ie: one each for reading, writing and both).
- how the control of access to these file manipulation functions is implemented, especially given that all of these constructors return generic (id) that don't give away at all whether they are of R/W/RW type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because on most operating systems (Mac OS X/iOS included), reading and writing are two separate operations, and a file handle that can do one is generally not able to do the other (unless explicitly opened with both access types.)

2) We don't know how `NSFileHandle` is implemented. :) Or maybe we do know, but it's an *implementation detail*, so even if we know we should pretend we don't.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Your answers make sense to me, but allow me to rephrase Question #2: Why not make the return type reflect what the returned object actually is / does (Eg: id<RdOnly> or id<WrOnly>)? Will that break some rules/coding convention for constructor signatures?

Comment: In short, yes, that would break coding convention. The coding convention has a logical basis, however: if the return types of convenience methods were strongly-typed, subclasses would not be able to use the same method signatures. Consider `+[NSString string]` vs. `+[NSMutableString string]`. If the former returned `NSString *` instead of `id`, the latter could not return a mutable string (even if it did, which it does, the caller would not know it.)

Comment: But NSFileHandle has v/ specific convenience constructors. Seems that any subclass, if it chose to subclass them, should still return objects that still work the same way. eg: since `fileHandleForReadingAtPath` returns FH used for reading only, we could have a protocol (say, `ReadOnlyFH`), and the method signature could then be `+(id<ReadOnlyFH>) fileHandleForReadingAtPath:(NSString*)path`. The subclass is still free to expand / change the implementation of the returned object.

Comment: Sorry about all the questions and thanks for your responses. I'm just trying to understand this.

Comment: It could do that, except that such protocols don't exist, so it doesn't. :) Your code should be able to determine if an `NSFileHandle` is open for reading or writing if you design said code well.

Comment: Well I only write bad code ;) . Thanks for your responses. I can certainly live with this. It's just that I'm still trying to familiarize myself with Cocoa way of life, including its best practices and paradigms.

Comment: `NSFileHandle` is one of those archaic classes that's been around for ages. I honestly don't think I've seen any production code use it--everyone who needs to write/read a file uses `NSData` or just plain old `fopen()`/`open()`. But since `NSFileHandle` isn't fundamentally broken in any way, Apple seems content to leave it undeprecated.